# How to avoid big chunks of copied code related with layout views?

Tags: android

I am currently working on a project and I've noticed I end up copying big chunks of code quite often. I know it's not how one should do it, but I haven't found a better way yet. Most often I just need to set ImageResource to a layout object based on a specific value. It's really a pain to repeat this for 25 times and change img1 to img2 and so on. **Is there a way on how to do it more properly and faster?** See example below.

**A small example of what I mean**

```
    if(!b1){
        foobar = rewardrandom.nextInt(100)+1;
        if (foobar <= 40){
            r1= 0;
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty);
        }
        if (foobar > 40 && foobar <=70){
            r1= 1;
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
        }
        if (foobar > 70 && foobar<=90){
            r1= 2;
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
        }
        if (foobar > 90){
            r1= 3;
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.item3);
        }
    }
    if(!b2){
        foobar = rewardrandom.nextInt(100)+1;
        if (foobar <= 40){
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty);
            r2 = 0;
        }
        if (foobar > 40 && foobar <=70){
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
            r2 = 1;
        }
        if (foobar > 70 && foobar<=90){
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
            r2 = 2;
        }
        if (foobar > 90){
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.item3);
            r2 = 3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: b1 and b2 boolean are same(i ask you write mistakenly) or different boolean varible ?

Comment: b1 and b2 are not the same. And the problem is that I have 25 of them and I have to just copy this code and replace b1, r1, img1, to b2,r2,img2 and so on.It's basically the same code, but different variables. Is there a way to shorten this into a loop or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can shorten it by making a method like this**

```
private int yourMethodName (boolean condition, ImageView img, int r){
    if (!condition){
        foobar = rewardrandom.nextInt(100)+1;

        if (foobar <= 40){
            r = 0;
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty);
        }
        if (foobar > 40 && foobar <=70){
            r = 1;
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
        }
        if (foobar > 70 && foobar<=90){
            r = 2;
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
        }
        if (foobar > 90){
            r = 3;
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.item3);
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

**and use it like this**

```
    r1 = yourMethodName(b1, img1, r1);
    r2 = yourMethodName(b2, img2, r2);
    r2 = yourMethodName(b3, img3, r3);
    // etc...
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of that. Huge thanks.